# Find the number of strings with a total of $m$ 1s & $k$ 0s if any two consecutive 1s must have at least $j$ 0s separating them.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering whether a combinatorial formula can be generated from the following problem using the stars and bars method:

> Find the number of strings with a total of $m$ 1s & $k$ 0s if any two consecutive 1s must have at least $j$ 0s separating them.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be infinite, given the current constraints? Unless by 'lots' you don't mean clusters, but amount.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not making that clear. I mean amount, not groups. I am trying to come up with a combinatorial formula that would work for all cases.

Comment: I think the standard way to say that would be "$m$ 1s and $k$ 0s". One idea: make a new object that is a 1 followed by $j$ 0s. Then you have $m-1$ of the new objects, one leftover 1s that will serve as the last 1 placed, and $k-(m-1)j$ extra 0s. A stars-and-bars argument on these objects might well work (the only wrinkle being that the leftover $1$ must be to the right of all the new 100...00 objects).

Answer (score 1):

Let's work with Greg Martin's idea.  Since there must be at least $j$ zeros between any two ones, set aside $(m - 1)j$ zeros.  Then we are left with $m$ ones and $k - (m - 1)j$ zeros, so we have $m + k - (n - 1)j$ positions to fill.  Choose $m$ of these $m + k - (m - 1)j$ positions for the ones and fill the remainder with zeros.  This can be done in
$$\binom{m + k - (m - 1)j}{m}$$
ways.  Now insert a block of $j$ zeros to the immediate right of the first $m - 1$ ones to ensure that each pair of successive ones are separated by at least $j$ zeros.

To illustrate, suppose we have $5$ ones and $15$ zeros and that there must be at least three zeros between each pair of ones. Set aside $(5 - 1) \cdot 3 = 4 \cdot 3 = 12$ zeros.  That leaves us with five ones and three zeros.  Choose five of these eight positions for the ones, which can be done in 
$$\binom{8}{5}$$
ways.  One such arrangement is
$$1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0$$
If we now insert three zeros to the immediate right of the first four ones using our twelve remaining zeros, we obtain
$$1 \color{blue}{0 0 0} 1 \color{blue}{0 0 0} 0 0 1 \color{blue}{0 0 0} 1 \color{blue}{0 0 0} 1 0$$
which is an arrangement of five ones and fifteen zeros in which each pair of successive ones is separated by at least three zeros.